# No implementation found for method createSourceWithParams on channel stripe_payment IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, stripe-payments

I was building a payment module in flutter using stripe payment gateway and it was working fine on android , Recently i needed to build the IOS version too , But when I'm trying to trigger the createSourceWithParams() function for the payment, IOS throwing an error

> Error occured MissingPluginException(No implementation found for
> method createSourceWithParams on channel stripe_payment)

Then i tried for only help ,
Tried flutter clean
Tried rm -rf pod , rm -rf podfile , pod repo update , pod install [ RESETTING THE PODS ]
while installing the pods , The dependency versions are

- Installing Firebase (6.34.0)
- Installing FirebaseAnalytics (6.9.0)
- Installing FirebaseCore (6.10.4)
- Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics(1.7.0)
- Installing FirebaseInstallations (1.7.0)
- Installing FirebaseInstanceID (4.8.0)
- Installing FirebaseMessaging (4.7.1)
- Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
- Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.9.0)
- Installing GoogleDataTransport (7.5.1)
- Installing GoogleUtilities (6.7.2)
- Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.11)
- Installing Protobuf (3.13.0)
- Installing Stripe (20.1.0)
- Installing TOCropViewController (2.5.5)
- Installing firebase_messaging (0.0.1)
- Installing flashy_tab_bar (0.0.1)
- Installing flutter_local_notifications (0.0.1)
- Installing flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle (0.0.1)
- Installing flutter_visualizers (0.0.1)
- Installing image_cropper (0.0.2)
- Installing image_picker (0.0.1)
- Installing nanopb (1.30906.0)
- Installing streaming_radio_flutter_plugin (0.0.1)
- Installing stripe_payment (1.0.0)

I specified stripe_payment 1.0.8 in pubspec.yaml and POD is installing version 1.0.0 ,
I tried to change the IOS Version 10.0,11.0,9.0 in the podfile and restarted all the above processes , But it still throwing the error .

In the Stripe_payment 1.0.0 pub.dev documentation also includes the function createsourcewithparams() with same arguments as in Stripe_payment 1.0.8

Working fine on android , but not on ios ,

Please help !!
Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a problem with my Appdelegate.swift , i accidently replaced the code from firebase with the existing Appdelegate.swift code ..

Wrong Implementation

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Flutter 

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
    
}
```

RIGHT IMPLEMENTATION

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        // <-- 2nd add

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

May help someone .. :)